# Else master will never be excuted in successor() in treemap

Tags: java, treemap

I'm learning sourcecode of remove() in treemap. But there is something i can't understand.

//....................ignore major codes,left these

```
private void deleteEntry(Entry<K,V> p) {

if (p.left != null && p.right != null) {





        Entry<K,V> s = successor(p);
        p.key = s.key;
        p.value = s.value;
        p = s;
}
```

}

```
static <K,V> TreeMap.Entry<K,V> successor(Entry<K,V> t) {`enter code here`
    if (t == null)
        return null;
    else if (t.right != null) {
        Entry<K,V> p = t.right;
        while (p.left != null)
            p = p.left;
        return p;
    } else {
        Entry<K,V> p = t.parent;
        Entry<K,V> ch = t;
        while (p != null && ch == p.right) {
            ch = p;
            p = p.parent;
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

I felt confused in deleteEntry function, p has 2 kids. P.left and P.right all 
 aren't null.
 but why dose it judge that t.right is not empty in successor function?
 I mean that it's absoulte fact. And because t.right must be
 not null. Codes never be excuted in else master in successor function.

Who call tell me where is my problem?  Thank you ,guys.

Comment: So what? Is that the only place where `successor` is ever called? To reason about the corner cases of `successor` you cannot just look at one caller of it, you have to look at all possible callers.

Comment: thank you guys.I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at TreeMap.java , you will get to know that successor is getting called from many places, delete() is just one such place.